# 2Dのビームをy回転のみ追従するようにしたい

Tags: unity3d

UnityのParticalSyatemで横に発射するビームを作りたいのですがYのみカメラに追従するような設定はないでしょうか？（VerticalBillbordの横方向バージョンのような感じ）設定しながら見たいのでParticalSystem上の設定でお願いします。[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]